# DynamoDB throwing undefined values error despite being able to write to DB using different array to PUT to DB

Tags: javascript, typescript, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a method that's making a call to a table with the following schema:
userId: string | sessionId: string | orders: list
Here's the following code:

```
const marshallOptions = {
    convertEmptyValues: false,
    removeUndefinedValues: false,
    convertClassInstanceToMap: false,
  };
  
const unmarshallOptions = {
    wrapNumbers: false,
  };
  
const translateConfig = { marshallOptions, unmarshallOptions };

const client: DynamoDBClient = new DynamoDBClient({});
const dynamo: DynamoDBDocument = DynamoDBDocument.from(client, translateConfig);

async function handleOrder(event: APIGatewayProxyEventV2): Promise<string> {
    let req: any = JSON.parse(String(event?.body));
    // Get student's orders
    let studentOrderSubmissions: any = await dynamo.send(new GetCommand({
        TableName: orderBook,
        Key: {
            userId: req.userId,
            sessionId: sessionIdPlaceholder
        }
    }))
    let studentOrders: any = studentOrderSubmissions.Item?.orders;
    const orderInfo: OrderInfo = {
        orderNumber: req.orderNumber,
        userId: req.userId,
        price: req.price,
        position: req.position,
        isLong: req.isLong,
        isBuy: req.isBuy,
        quantity: req.quantity,
        closedOut: req.closedOut
    } 
    studentOrders.push(orderInfo);
    const params = {
        TableName: orderBook,
        Item: {
            userId: req.userId,
            sessionId: req.sessionId,
            orders: studentOrders
        }
    };
    await dynamo.put(params, function(err: any, data: any) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error", err);
        } 
        else {
            console.log("Success", data);
        }
    });
```

When modifying the studentOrders array pushing a new student order into it, after trying to PUT the changes into DynamoDb into the OrderBook table, I always get the following error:
`Pass options.removeUndefinedValues=true to remove undefined values from map/array/set.` EVEN after setting marshall options.removeUndefinedValues to false (despite it by default being false).

When I create a new array with the following code:

```
const testArray: any = [];
testArray.push(orderInfo);
```

and replace studentOrders with testArray, DynamoDB saves the data and doesn't throw an error.
Is this because DynamoDB doesn't allow you to pass in an array from itself? How would one update a list attribute in a table then? If I can't use `put` or `PutCommand` that leaves me with the query options and writing a new query but I figured I'd ask more experienced people first if they've ever run into this problem.

Comment: It's not clear what client you're using or how you've set it up. Can you provide more details.

Comment: @LeeHannigan I've gone ahead and edited my post to show how I've set up the dynamo client. I don't believe this is the issue however, my hunch is telling me that DynamoDB probably doesn't support operations for modifying lists and it'd be better to use a map instead, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what the issue was. My object wasn't undefined. What was undefined was my sort key! It was throwing an error letting me know one of my values being passed into the parameters was undefined but didn't tell me which one specifically. With that being said the error was here:

```
Item: {
   userId: req.userId,
   sessionId: req.sessionId,
   orders: studentOrders
}
```

**I never defined req.sessionId, SO THAT was what was causing the freak out! It really should've been cannot pass undefined KEY rather than just say that you can't pass an undefined value.**